# Why is Resources.resx emptied after every build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, localization

I add entries in resources.resx file manually but these would get removed after every build of the project. Is it the default behavior? Or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: This is not default behaviour. Check for any build events which are clearing it out.

Comment: if you dont do it literally manually by altering pure text, then the values should not clear. Check naming, possible interference with other resource file or redo it from the beginning ..

Comment: Ok... I am looking ... but till now no success :(

Comment: Are you using the Designer in Visual Studio. By designer, I mean are you editing from the excel like view, or outside Visual Studio directly in the xml file? If you are editing outside Visual Studio, then you have to manually add the respective function for that string in the designer file.

Comment: I found it, I implemented Localization through LanguageResourceUpdater.exe and I was passing -c argument $(SolutionDir)\References\LanguageResourceUpdater.exe -c ..... So just after removing that argument, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I add entries in resources.resx file manually

Don't do that.  You'll lose these changes when the .resx file is re-generated by the Resource Designer.  Which makes an effort to keep the Resources.resx in sync with the Resources.Designer.cs file.  Use Project + Properties, Resources tab to make changes.

Comment: Although I am entering them manually, I user Project+Properties to add the entries.